# Android Layout Performance Tests

Tags: android, android-layout, performance-testing

I'm planning to do some experiments with different types of Android layouts to see how their performances are compared to each other. I notice there maybe a tool to do performance test (as showed in this image - http://leaks.wanari.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/constraint_profile-1.png from this blog post http://leaks.wanari.com/2016/05/31/constraintlayout-android/).

I haven't been searching for a while but couldn't find what that tool is. Please let me know if anyone knows it.

Thanks

Comment: [Hierarchy Viewer](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer-walkthru.html)

Comment: Thanks! That's the one I'm looking for